# {member_group} not working in conditional

Tags: templates, members, conditionals

I have the following code:

```
{exp:member:custom_profile_data}
        <div class="profile">
            {member_group}
            {if member_group == "Super Admins"}You are a Super Admin{/if}
        </div>
{/exp:member:custom_profile_data}
```

Member group is being displayed correctly, but it doesn't work in conditional. I would appreciate if anyone can explain what I'm doing wrong or how else to add a member group specific content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I've figured it out, so {member_group} displays the name of the member group, but placed in conditional it requires an ID of the member group. Works now!